# Tuleap on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, installation, tuleap

Is it possible to have a full installation (not via a dockers container) of Tuleap on Ubuntu?

According to the official documenation (e.g., https://www.tuleap.org/full-installation) only CentOS and RedHat seem to be supported.

Answer (score 0):

No. Only CentOS/Redhat are supported. Apart from that, Docker is the only way to install tuleap on other distributions.

Answer (score -3):

You have answered your own question. Tuleap team provides build for CentOS / Redhat systems only. Other option would be to probably do the configuration by hand.